# Records within each location of an object and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a problem, I want to save each record in an array but every time I do it, only the last one is saved, what could be happening? Or how you could save an object with different attributes in each record or row.

```
let obj = [];
// new ite
let item = {};
item.price = "11.11";
item.type = "1";
item.text = "Variante 3";
item.title = "Size 4";
item.label = "size4";

obj.push( item );

item.price = "0.11";
item.type = "0";
item.text = "Variante 0";
item.title = "Size 0";
item.label = "size0";

obj.push( item );

console.log( obj );
```

Result:

```
{
  label: "size0",
  price: "0.11",
  text: "Variante 0",
  title: "Size 0",
  type: "0"
}
```

Comment: the result should contain 2 items already. Please see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp. The keyword you are looking for is `reference type`

Comment: If you're having an issue with this code, it's because there's code or structure you aren't showing us. There is no problem with the code posted.

Comment: it contains 2 items, but each item is the exact same thing.. objects point/refer to "data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You modifying the reference of the first object you pushed, one solution would be to reset `item`:

```js
let obj = [];
// new ite
let item = {};
item.price = "11.11";
item.type = "1";
item.text = "Variante 3";
item.title = "Size 4";
item.label = "size4";

obj.push( item );

item = {}; // add this
item.price = "0.11";
item.type = "0";
item.text = "Variante 0";
item.title = "Size 0";
item.label = "size0";

obj.push( item );

console.log( obj );
```

Comment: indeed.. make item point to a new object every time.. thi is the complete answer